# How to clear browser cache in React Create App

Tags: reactjs, caching, create-react-app, browser-cache

I'm really struggling with Cache Busting on my Create React App.

I can see that the hash of my bundles are changing but users are still seeing old versions of the app on each deploy.

I've tried disabling the serviceworker

I've tried using the react-cache-buster

I'd be most grateful if anyone could talk me through their process of testing and implementing CacheBusting on a Create React App.

So far this is my code:

```
//App.js file 
  <CacheBuster
  currentVersion={packInfo.version}
  isEnabled={true} //If false, the library is disabled.
  isVerboseMode={true} //If true, the library writes verbose logs to console.
>  
// Load App() component here
```

Then in my index.js I'm not registering the Service Worker.  I'm testing this in Chrome Console, and I can confirm that no Service Worker is being registered

```
// index.js
   import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Then I run `npm run build` followed by `npm start`

Then I go and check my browser network tab

Sometimes (I think) it is making the xhr request to meta.json and checking the version number in package.json

But it always outputs: `There is no new version. No cache refresh needed.`

When I deploy to Netlify on production I see the same log.

The HTML header have the following set:

`cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`

Does anyone have any ideas how I can sort this problem out?

Comment: I would also love you know how did you solve it!? It is driving me crazy

Comment: Same with me.. @Linda How did you solve it?